# Prevent reloading of Page on oncomplete of actionfunction

Tags: rerender, button, actionfunction, oncomplete

I have below code where I want to do an action to apex action function and oncomplete of it want to call a javascript function.

Unfortunately instead of calling the action the action function in my case, performs oncomplete javascript function call and then reloads the page.

Can anyone please help me know why such weird behavior happening here?

```
 <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" onclick="return actfun();"><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"> &nbsp; &nbsp; Download XML</i></button>
                           <apex:actionfunction name="actfun" action="{!getProcessing}"  oncomplete="move();" rerender="searchSection2"/>
```

**Move function code**

```
<script>
        function move() {
          var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");   
          var width = 1;
          var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
          function frame() {
            if (width >= 100) {
              clearInterval(id);
            } else {
              width++; 
              elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
            }
          }

        }
        </script>
```

Comment: Is the reload code present in javaScript method `move`? Also, did you debug and check if it is not at all going inside the method `getProcessing`?

Comment: Yes it's not going as if I remove oncomplete and rerender parts it perfectly goes to getprocessing and downloads an xml for me as expected.

Answer (score 1):

With a normal button, you want to cancel the original operation:

```
 <button onclick="actfun(); return false;">...</button>
```

This will prevent your whole-page-reload scenario.